# Any finite dimensional extension is contained in a finite dimensional normal extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I am new to this website so I'm not really sure what I'm doing, but here it goes.

I have no idea how to do this.  I know that an extension is normal if the irreducible polynomial of any element of the extension splits over the field.  I am guessing that we can take some polynomial and extend the field by roots of it or something, but i don't know

Comment: Try thinking through an example. E.g. what is a normal extension containing $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$, or more generally $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, or in complete generality $k(\alpha_1,\ldots \alpha_n)$? The key fact is that splitting fields are normal.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Can you walk me through one of those examples?  I don't see any examples in the notes of finding normal extensions for field extensions.  I just see a theorem that says any galois extension is normal.  With regard to the original question, I now see that for H to be a splitting field it just needs to be the splitting field of a single polynomial over F in the finite dimensional case

Comment: "I am guessing that we can take some polynomial and extend the field by roots of it or something, but i don't know"  That's exactly what you do.

Comment: @D_S Is this correct?  Let f be an irreducible polynomial over $F$ with roots {$u_1,u_2,..,u_n$} (finitely many because the extension is finite dimensional).  Then $H=E(u_1, u_2, ..., u_n)$ is a normal extension.

Comment: That will be a normal extension of $E$, not necessarily of $F$.

Comment: @D_S Any hint on how to find one of $F$?  It's not just $F(u_1, u_2, ..., u_n)$, is it?

Comment: @D_S we are given $F \subset E$ and we want to find a normal extension $F \subset H$

Comment: which contains $E$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be an algebraically closed field containing $E$.  Since $E$ is finite over $F$, we can write $E = F(a_1, ... , a_n)$ for some $a_i \in \Omega$, algebraic over $F$.  Each $a_i$ is the root of an irreducible polynomial $f_i$ with coefficients in $F$.  Obtain the required normal extension by adjoining to $F$ (or to $E$) all of the roots of all the $f_i$ (which lie in $\Omega$, since $\Omega$ is algebraically closed).